# good practice - similarly named variables

Tags: c++

Trivial issue, but comes up a lot for me, and I imagine others too.  Does anybody have a really good, really clever solution?

```
void some_function (obj &A, obj &B)
{
// do stuff with A...
//e.g.
double number_A = (value - A.member_func() ) * A.other_func();


// do stuff with B.  similar BUT NOT EXACTLY like A...
//e.g.
double number_B = (value + B.member_func()  )   *   A.other_func();  
  // !!!!
  // Big time TYPO  -   should say "B.other_func()", not "A.other_func()" !!!!   
  // !!!!
}
```

Any good guards against these types of errors?

I often have to work on two analogous variables, say one named version "A" and the other "B".

Because the code for each one is similar, I often use the code that worked on "A" as a "template" (i.e. copy & paste) for the code that works on "B" - making the small adjustments so that the code becomes appropriate for B.

Becuase I am human, I sometimes forget to change "A" to "B" in certain locations when copying the code.  If I am lucky, this will cause the program to crash.  Either way, this is disastrous.

Does anybody know any clever tricks for preventing such typos?

I've thought of...

- enclosing brackets `{ }` to try to restrict the scope of variables - but if objects A and B are in the function arguments, then this doesn't solve it.
- dividing every function into sub-functions - one for A and one for B.  This is a bit cumbersome from the developer perspective (passing/returning many of variables).
- work only with *pointers* to the objects themselves - not the actual objects.  This way we can `{ scope-control }` the pointers.  Also cumbersome, (and the overhead for defining a pointer is negligible, even if I call the function very, very often, right?)

Comment: One really great way to catch these is to do code reviews before you submit.  Unit testing may catch them as well.

Comment: It's all in the title: don't name them similarly. But really, such mistakes should make your tests fail. If they don't, then they don't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example you give, the best defence is to do as little as possible in each function:

```
void some_function (obj &A, obj &B)
{
    double number_A = do_stuff(A);
    double number_B = do_similar_stuff(B);
}

double do_stuff(obj &A) {
    return (value - A.member_func() ) * A.other_func();
}

// EITHER
double do_similar_stuff(obj &A) {
    // no variable rename when copying == no problem
    return value + A.member_func()  )   *   A.other_func();
}
// OR
double do_similar_stuff(obj &B) {
    // A not in scope == very brief problem until compiler tells us
    return value + B.member_func()  )   *   A.other_func();
    // Beware, also, the nightmare scenario that there's some *other* 
    // `A` in scope, so this *still* compiles. For that reason, prefer
    // the other option unless there's some good reason why this parameter 
    // should be `B`, and don't name member function parameters the same 
    // as data members etc.
}
```

Alternatively, you could make the relation between the two kinds of "stuff" explicit. Assuming that the unmatched parenthesis in your `B` code is supposed to go in the same place as the `A`. It all depends whether there really is a logical relationship between the two similar-looking operations:

```
void some_function (obj &A, obj &B)
{
    double number_A = do_stuff(A, true);
    double number_B = do_stuff(B, false);
}

double do_stuff(obj &A, bool subtract) {
    // yeah, never call variables "tmp". Unless you have no context
    // to give them meaning.
    // Depending on the type of `tmp`, there might be a better way to
    // write this, using multiplication by -1. But let's not assume, we'll do
    // one refactor at a time.
    auto tmp = subtract ? value - A.member_func() : value + A.member_func();
    return tmp * A.other_func();
}
```

Other examples will vary. As you say it can be tiresome to write, but it has a number of benefits other than catching this error. Not least is that it will direct you towards writing your code in a way that you try to *avoid* passing/returning many variables. As a consequence, each line of your code affects fewer other things in the program, which is basic code hygiene.

It may also mean you can test that your formula with `A` is correct independently of whether your formula with `B` is correct, and sundry other benefits of short functions.

Comment: In a theoretical example it might look hard to read because nothing means anything so there's no natural division. But in a complicated *real* project, these small functions help self-document the code, give *meaning* to syntax which is enforced by the compiler and constantly confirms the assumptions of coders. A huge +1 to this as the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @SteveJessop True, sorry, I guess it was a bad way to express myself there, anyway please excuse me and my lack in skill trying to communicate what I wanted to say, I removed the comment.

Comment: is it just me that understood his line with B should've looked like `double number_B = ( value + B.member_func()  )   *   B.other_func();` in which case you only needed the do_stuff function called once for A and once for B?

Comment: @xception: I certainly agree that it's possible to come up with examples of code where splitting into smaller functions doesn't help. There's also a style of C coding (e.g. GNU), which fairly concertedly writes large functions as implementations of the kind of function defined in the standard library, because "everything should be in front of you", you shouldn't have to go looking for anything or following up chains of indirection via functions and aliases. I'm not totally against that, with reasoning behind it, but the opposite really does help with this kind of code flaw caused by c'n'p.

Comment: @xception: I thought the *intended* difference between the two was supposed to be `- A.member_func()` for A, and `+ B.member_func()` for B.

Comment: than why did he write `// Big time TYPO  -   should "B.other_func()", not "A.other_func()" !!!` right after that?

Comment: @xception: there are two differences between the pieces of code. One is the missing left paren, which I think the questioner was unaware of. One was the +/-, which I think the questioner intends to be the correct difference between the snippets (aside from one using A and the other B). There is one similarity in the code `* A.other_func()`, which I believe the questioner wrote deliberately, but that it represents an example of an easy bug to write. The "correct" code should be `B.other_func()` in the B case, and the comment indicates that this is the bug being illustrated.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the +/- difference that's why I said you only needed one function. I should read more carefully.

Comment: I added the left parnthese `(` for the `number_B` line.  - that was a genuine typo in writing the post

Comment: The +/- difference is too emphasize that the operations are only *very slightly* different.  the `A.other_func()` in the `number_B` line was supposed to **SIMULATE** a typo - hence the comment ("big time typo") right after it. @xception

Comment: @SteveJessop  your interpretation is 100% correct.  That is exactly as I intended.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few ideas in mind

1. you could use snippets if your editor supports them or move to an editor/ide which has support for them (personally I use kdevelop and snippets are very useful as they replace all occurences of a snippet variable)
2. you could also use refactoring (in a separate function if you
   already used the names this one)
3. also selecting a piece of code and doing replace all in selection
   might help
4. using defines is also an option

Still, going with a smarter IDE is the best in my opinion.

Comment: I use KDevelop, too.  Is "refactoring" basically @SteveJessop 's answer?

Comment: Yes and no, refactoring is a good idea, however when writing that I was actually thinking about the rename declaration functionality from kdevelop. My communication skills are lacking though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is not have similar function names in other classes. Also, having unit tests coupled with peer code reviews should catch these errors *most* of the time. However, there have been many times in SW history where these types of errors are never caught until many days, months, or years later.

Comment: `A` and `B` have the same type, so similar functions names in other classes are irrelevant. It's an obvious limitation of static typing: it doesn't catch errors where you pass the *wrong* instance of the right type! I agree with the rest, though, testing and peer review "should" catch this error. And also have a chance of catching wide classes of other errors.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yea, I see your point. I misunderstood the OP. Good point.